# How does the work done by a cord-over-a-pulley work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

[image]

I can use the integral of power with respect to time to solve problem.

In this situation, what is the work done on the cart by the tension?

Please do not use calculus.

Comment: @DavidWhite $T\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\cos \theta_t |\vec v(t)| \mathrm dt=Td$

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated the work done (change in kinetic energy of the cart) using two approaches.  I thought the second approach could possibly be simpler, but it is not.  I had to use calculus for both approaches.  I cannot think of a simple way to evaluate the work.  The second approach evaluates the work done on a system of particles, a topic not addressed in many textbooks that discuss the motion of a system of particles.

Consider the system of interest as the cart. The work done on the cart is due to the net force on the cart.  The forces on the cart are $T$, the tension in the cord acting at an angle $\theta$ on the cart, $mg$ down, and $N$ the normal force up on the cart.  The only non-zero net force is in the horizontal direction due to $Tcos\theta$. This assumes no force of friction between the cart and the ground. Note that $\theta$ is not constant but increases as the cart moves left, and that needs to be accounted for in evaluating the work. The figure below shows the evaluation for work on the cart; the result is $W = T(d_2 - d_1)$ where $d_2 - d_1$ is the total distance the cord moves to the left of the pully.
[image]

To see if there is a simpler approach to evaluating the work, take the system as: the cart, the pully, and the portion of the cord from the pully to the cart.

First, the general relationships for a system of particles are summarized in the figure below. The general relationship for work done on a system of particles is not addressed in many texts, but is developed by Goldstein. [Goldstein, Classical Mechanics]  These relationships depend on the position of the particles with respect to the origin of an inertial reference frame, labeled $O$ in the figure, which can be specified as desired.
[image]

The general relationships can be applied to the system of interest here.  See the figure below.  This system is not a rigid body because the cart moves, but the only body in the system with mass is the cart, assuming a massless pully and massless cord.  The origin  $O$ is taken for convenience of calculation as the point where the cord outside the system enters the system. The only external force applied is  $\vec F_{ext} = \vec T$ , and the only body in the system to which this external force is applied is the massless pully; there is no external force applied to the cart.  The cart experiences an internal force from the cord, $\vec T$.  So the equation for work done on this system is due to the internal force on the cart.  As developed in the figure, using this approach we need to evaluate the same integral as was previously evaluated for the case where the system in the cart alone.  So, this approach does not simplify the evaluation of work.
I am not aware of any other approach that would simplify the evaluation of work.
[image]

The tension force in the cord is constant over the entire cord assuming a massless string and massless pully and no friction loss on the pully. Once the cart starts to move, the cord very quickly stretches a minor bit to provide tension, but then the cord acts as a rigid body and there is no change in the length of the cord.  The speed of each particle in the cord is the same.  Specifically, a mass element $\Delta m$ with speed $v$ in the string moves a distance $\Delta s = v \Delta t$ in the time $\Delta t$, and since the string length is constant, over $\Delta t$ the distance $\Delta s$ is constant for each element $\Delta m$ of the string therefore $v$ is constant for element of the string

Comment: $d$ is not the horizontal distance the cart moves. It is the length of cord that moves when the cart moves. The cord is not parallel to the ground.

Comment: I can see how the speed of each particle in the left part of the cord is the same. But I do not know if that is the case for the right part. Can you prove it?

Comment: If the speed of each particle is the same, then the work done on the cart is the same as the work done on the cord by the force that pulls the cord in the left-bottom corner?

Comment: You don't know what is the purpose of the first paragraph. And can you prove why the speed is the same rather than stating it?

Comment: I was asking to show the work done is $Fd$ in a simle way.

Comment: Oops, d is not the distance the cart moves. I updated my answer.   Also, the update evaluates the work using a hard way and a simple way.

Comment: Why is the distance travelled by each particle in the right part of the string in a time interval the same?

Comment: The distance travelled by any particle in the string is the same, because the string length is constant, effectively a rigid body, and for a rigid body the distance between any two points is constant. "In physics, a rigid body (also known as a rigid object) is a solid body in which deformation is zero or so small it can be neglected. The distance between any two given points on a rigid body remains constant in time regardless of external forces or moments exerted on it."  This is why $d + r$ is constant in the figure.

Comment: But consider A attached to B such that  the distance between the two is constant. A moves in a short line segment from one point to another while B revolves around A in light speed. The distance between the two is the same but the distances travelled by two are different.

Comment: OK, I see.  I am addressing the distance between any two particles in the string, not the absolute distance a given particle moves in the reference frame, such as rotation of B about A.  The problem assumes a massless cord, so why are you concerned with this?  The tension determines the work, and it is constant everywhere in the cord for massless cord, massless piston, and no friction in the piston. Constant string length means $d+r$ is constant, and that with $T$ constant allows the solution.

Comment: I know that the work done by a constant force on a particle is $\cos \theta Fd$ But why is the work done by the tension on the cart-cord system is also $Fd$? Also, why is the external force tension? Isn't cord part of the system? Do you mean the hidden force that pulls the cord that creates this tension?

Comment: How is the tension an external force when the cord is in the system? And what does it mean for a system to move? Its contituents all move differently.

Comment: The system is: pully, cart, and the part of the cord between the pully and the cart.  
The part of the cord to the left of the pully is not part of the system. $T$ on the right end of the cord outside the system pulls on the system. $F$ pulls on the left end of the cord that is outside the system; for a massless cord $T$ = $F$ in the part of the cord outside the system. $T$ is horizontal and moves through the horizontal distance $d_2 - d_1$ ,so the work is the scalar product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135208/discussion-between-john-darby-and-tfr).